# How to clear all form values on success in stripe (React)?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe API for payment. I want to clear all the fields when payment is successfully made by the user.

HTML:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <CardElement onChange={handleCardChange} />
  <button type="submit" disabled={!stripe}>
    Submit Payment
  </button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
const handleServerResponse = (serverResponse) => {
    if (serverResponse.error) {
      // An error happened when charging the card,
      // show the error in the payment form.
    } else {
      // Show a success message
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stripe [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/other_methods/clear)

Inside success block, add this:

```
elements.getElement(CardElement).clear();
```

**OR**

If you are using Split payment form you have to clear each element individually.

```
elements.getElement(CardNumberElement).clear();
elements.getElement(CardExpiryElement).clear();
elements.getElement(CardCvcElement).clear();
```

Comment: what to do if only I need to empty the values of stripe card elements!??